# Is Possible to test Web Application in Windows 7 for IPhone Emulators?

Tags: iphone, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I want to test my web application in iPhone Emulator but I have only Windows Machine there is any way to create iPhone emulators on Windows for testing web applications using Appium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way if you create a Virtual Machine of MAC OS. But you still need a valid MAC OS license (there is no freeware except some hacked ones).

Basically you need XCode application to run iOS emulators, which can be installed only on MAC OS.

Comment: Thanks for your Response Kristaps.